# pandas: Output all rows in Series with a marginally low frequency

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, series

Line using value_counts to create frequency table for a column named `datecreated`

`autos['datecreated'].str[:10].value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=False)`

This next line is the one where I am getting the errors or just not the result I want, I want to view the rows in which the `datacreated` is lower than `0.0001`

`autos['datecrawled'].str[:10].value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=False) < 0.0001`

Comment: Please provide the error and part of the data frame so that the error can be reproduced.

Comment: Please provide some sample data in a text format. Edit your post to contain this information. For more information, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples